# Opscenter does not recognize the Version 5.1.3 of the datastax-agent

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I installed Opscenter 5.1.3 and updated also the datastax-agent on the nodes to Version 5.1.3. Anyway the OpsCenter comes up with the message:

"Opscenter 11 agents need to be upgraded to 5.1.3. Clicking "Fix Now" will install and start the correct agent on these nodes"

Answer (score 1):

check in your datastax-agent directory. Are there multiple versions of the agent jar file?

`datastax-agent-5.1.2-standalone.jar
datastax-agent-5.1.3-standalone.jar`

If so, either rename or delete the older version and restart datastax-agent.